# UIAutomator working with android timepicker

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, ui-testing

I'm trying to perform UI testing for the android time picker.

I'm using espresso that cannot connect to this type of component and according to the documentation I should use `UIAutomator`. I can catch the OK/Cancel button using the following API

```
mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("OK")).click();
```

However, when I'm trying to set the time and hour I keep getting a `UiObjectNotFoundException`.

Has anyone managed to be able to set a time with this API?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example of how this can be achieved using [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which in turn indirectly uses UiAutomator.

I started generated a base test script with `culebra` that I later customized (with the device as the same screen as you show in your screenshot). Unfortunately [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI) is not generating such complex tests **yet**, but the auto-generated test is a very good place to start.

```
$ culebra -d true -i true -CVLU -o ~/tmp/time-picker.py
```

You can find more about the options executing `culebra --help` but basically `-d` is telling it to use content descriptions, `-i` to use ids to and some logging options followed by the output file.

Then i edited the auto-generated file to look like this (I added some comment to make it self explanatory)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013-2014  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2016-02-19 by Culebra v11.5.1
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os


import unittest


try:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
except:
    pass

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient, CulebraTestCase

TAG = 'CULEBRA'


class CulebraTests(CulebraTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': True, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
        cls.kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
        cls.options = {'start-activity': None, 'concertina': False, 'device-art': None, 'use-jar': False, 'multi-device': False, 'unit-test-class': True, 'save-screenshot': None, 'use-dictionary': False, 'glare': False, 'dictionary-keys-from': 'id', 'scale': 0.5, 'find-views-with-content-description': True, 'window': -1, 'orientation-locked': None, 'save-view-screenshots': None, 'find-views-by-id': True, 'log-actions': True, 'use-regexps': False, 'null-back-end': False, 'auto-regexps': None, 'do-not-verify-screen-dump': False, 'verbose-comments': True, 'gui': False, 'find-views-with-text': True, 'prepend-to-sys-path': True, 'install-apk': None, 'drop-shadow': False, 'output': '/home/diego/tmp/time-picker.py', 'unit-test-method': None, 'interactive': False}
        cls.sleep = 5

    def setUp(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).tearDown()

    def preconditions(self):
        if not super(CulebraTests, self).preconditions():
            return False
        return True

    def testSomething(self):
        if not self.preconditions():
            self.fail('Preconditions failed')

        _s = CulebraTests.sleep
        _v = CulebraTests.verbose

        self.device.Log.d(TAG, "dumping content of window='-1'",  _v)
        self.vc.dump(window='-1')


        # class=android.widget.TextView  text=u'10'
        self.device.Log.d(TAG, "finding view with id=android:id/hours",  _v)
        android___id_hours = self.vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("android:id/hours")

        # class=android.widget.TextView  text=u'30'
        self.device.Log.d(TAG, "finding view with id=android:id/minutes",  _v)
        android___id_minutes = self.vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("android:id/minutes")

        # class=android.view.View
        #self.device.Log.d(TAG, "finding view with id=android:id/radial_picker",  _v)
        #android___id_radial_picker = self.vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("android:id/radial_picker")

        # class=android.widget.RadialTimePickerView$RadialPickerTouchHelper  cd='0'
        hs = {}
        for h in range(0, 24):
            self.device.Log.d(TAG, "finding view with cd %s" % h,  _v)
            hs[h] = self.vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise(u'''%s''' % h)

        # class=android.widget.Button  text=u'Cancel'
        self.device.Log.d(TAG, "finding view with text Cancel",  _v)
        android___id_button2 = self.vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'Cancel')

        # class=android.widget.Button  text=u'OK'
        self.device.Log.d(TAG, "finding view with text OK",  _v)
        android___id_button1 = self.vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'OK')

        # Set time (for example 12:15)
        self.device.Log.d(TAG, "setting hour to 12",  _v)
        hs[12].touch()

        # Verify hour
        self.device.Log.d(TAG, "dumping content of window='-1'",  _v)
        self.vc.dump(window='-1')

        # class=android.widget.TextView  text=u'12'
        self.device.Log.d(TAG, "finding view with id=android:id/hours",  _v)
        android___id_hours = self.vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("android:id/hours")

        self.device.Log.d(TAG, "checking hour set to 12",  _v)
        self.assertEqual(android___id_hours.getText(), u'12')

        # update
        self.device.Log.d(TAG, "dumping content of window='-1'",  _v)
        self.vc.dump(window='-1')


        ms = {}
        for m in range(0, 60, 5):
            m0 = '%02d' % m
            self.device.Log.d(TAG, "finding view with cd %s" % m0,  _v)
            ms[m] = self.vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise(u'''%s''' % m)

        ms[15].touch()

        # Verify minute
        self.device.Log.d(TAG, "dumping content of window='-1'",  _v)
        self.vc.dump(window='-1')

        # class=android.widget.TextView  text=u'15'
        self.device.Log.d(TAG, "finding view with id=android:id/minutes",  _v)
        android___id_minutes = self.vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("android:id/minutes")
        self.assertEqual(android___id_minutes.getText(), u'15')


        self.device.Log.d(TAG, "finding view with text Cancel",  _v)
        android___id_button2 = self.vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'Cancel')

        # let's cancel, so time is not set
        android___id_button2.touch()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CulebraTests.main()
```

The test has these main parts:

1. verifying that the starting point is the time picker (it will fail if not)
2. obtaining all the *hours* Views
3. setting hour to 12
4. verifying that 12 was set
5. obtaining all the *minutes* Views
6. setting minutes to 15
7. verifying that 15 was set
8. touching cancel to avoid setting the time

Because of the logging options you receive this output when you run it with `-v`:

```
$ ~/tmp/time-picker.py -v

testSomething (__main__.CulebraTests) ... Connecting to a device with serialno=.* with a timeout of 60 secs...
Connected to device with serialno=.*
Actual device serialno=XXXXXXXXXXX
CULEBRA: dumping content of window='-1'
CULEBRA: finding view with id=android:id/hours
CULEBRA: finding view with id=android:id/minutes
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 0
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 1
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 2
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 3
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 4
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 5
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 6
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 7
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 8
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 9
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 10
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 11
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 12
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 13
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 14
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 15
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 16
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 17
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 18
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 19
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 20
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 21
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 22
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 23
CULEBRA: finding view with text Cancel
CULEBRA: finding view with text OK
CULEBRA: setting hour to 12
CULEBRA: dumping content of window='-1'
CULEBRA: finding view with id=android:id/hours
CULEBRA: checking hour set to 12
CULEBRA: dumping content of window='-1'
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 00
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 05
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 10
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 15
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 20
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 25
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 30
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 35
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 40
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 45
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 50
CULEBRA: finding view with cd 55
CULEBRA: dumping content of window='-1'
CULEBRA: finding view with id=android:id/minutes
CULEBRA: finding view with text Cancel
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 21.399s

OK
```

hope this helps you